# Getting rid of the `My` namespace

Tags: vb.net, binary, compilation

I've been developing a `Vb.Net` app lately, and I'm trying to make it as lightweight as possible (ie make the binaries as small as possible).

I've done all the trivial stuff, but while browsing the binary with `ILDasm`, I noticed that it has a `My namespace`, with a lot of methods, although I don't use any of these in my program. It seems that there are default `Get/Set` methods for every form, and other methods.

Is there a way to get rid of those?
Or, can you show me a use case for the methods bundled by default in the binary?

***PS**: I guess it's not going to make a huge difference in binary size: I'm just asking this out of curiosity; why would the compiler bundle useless methods in every binaries? Perhaps I'll learn that these methods are actually used somewhere under the hood.*

**PPS**: Here's a minimal example:

```
Module Test
Sub Main()
End Sub
End Module
```

The output is:
[image: ILDasm output]

Comment: The `My` namespace is pretty useful, but if you want to remove all the methods can't you just hit "show all files", browse around for the `My` namespace (which is accessible! you just have to find it) and delete it? It's a bad idea to delete it unless you're sure you aren't planning on using it, since you can use `My.Settings` and other parts of the namespace in your program and I wind up using it in many of my programs.

Comment: There seems to be a minimum that is added directly by the compiler. See my edit =)

Comment: Edit note: the compilation command line is `vbc minimal.vb`, assuming the minimal code block was saved to `minimal.vb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After furious head-scratching...:

How much is included depends on the value of the `_MYTYPE` define. It's all documented in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233781.aspx), I failed to find it at first.

Answer (score 3):

Follow these steps:

1. Click `Show All Files` in the solution explorer
2. Open the `My Project` branch
3. Open the `Settings.settings` branch
4. Open `Settings.designer.vb`
5. Edit the `My` namespace as you wish

[image]

There is an additional `My` sub-namespace called `My.Resources` which is hiding under the `Resources.resx` branch.

Comment: I'd like to point out however that removing or editing the `My` namespace isn't a good idea as I mentioned in my comment above, you may find you need some functionality in it at a later point in your project.

Comment: Hmmmm... I already got rid of `Settings.settings` and `Resources.resx`; the vb compiler still bundles methods :/

Comment: @Clément Try emptying the namespace instead of getting rid of it entirely.

Comment: I've added details; this doesn't seem to be related to Visual Studio; In fact, IIUC, VS adds extensions to the My namespace, in the settings and resources files, but these aren't there is a minimal set of elements.

Comment: Got it to work, see my self-answer below. +1 anyway for the details and the advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove most of the generated types in the My namespace you will have to set the `_MYTYPE` define to `Empty`. To do so you will have to open the .vbproj file in a text editor (using Visual Studio you can do this by first unloading the project and than open it).

Look for the element `<MyType>` in the first `<PropertyGroup>` and change its value to `Empty`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{C6DC5A64-1E50-48B0-97A5-649D2D323E5E}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Some.Component</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Some.Component</AssemblyName>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <MyType>Empty</MyType>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I have not found a way of removing the InternalXmlHelper that is generated by Visual Studio.

As [Clément](https://stackoverflow.com/users/695591/clement) pointed out it is possible to [configure the My namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233781.aspx) using other values of the `_MYTYPE` define.

This procedure will work for Visual Studio 2012.